# COBERTURA configuration within SONAR

Tags: sonarqube, cobertura

I am using [SONAR](http://www.sonarsource.org/) for Code Quality checks of my projects. In one project I would like to know the code coverage of a library which is included in the classpath (maven dependency).

Is it possible to configure SONAR (with embedded [COBERTURA](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)) to also instrument the specific library for code coverage analysis? As cobertura instruments the bytecode this should be possible but I do not know if it is supported by cobertura (even indepentend from SONAR).

Any hints are welcome.

Regards
  Klaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to set up cobertura(maven target) yourself and import the results([See dynamic analysis](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters))

```
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=PATH_TO_RESULT
```

But I will not help much:

1. you would need the src files of the jar to see the coverage, otherwise you would just get  % numbers and I'm not even sure sonar will show the extra covered files
2. the coverage for your whole project will always include the % of the library, so it will go down

It is better to test each project with its own unit tests on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the _dynamic analysis_ tip. Unfortunatly I have no existing report which I could reuse but the option `sonar.includedModules` seems interesting. +1 for the moment!